# How to use vertical-align: middle; properly?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I want to have my list (nav) align to the center of an image (logo). I tried using `vertical-align: middle;`, but I couldn't get it to work when I floated the images left and right.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="head">
    <img id="logo" src="logo.png" />
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#head {
    margin-top: 2px;
    width: 100%;
}
    #logo {
        float: left;
        }

    ul#nav {
        float: right;
        }

        ul#nav li {
            display: inline;
            list-style-type: none;
            }
```

I took all the `vertical-align: middle;`'s from where I put them (I tested it in each element, even though it was only supposed to be applied to #logo, from what I've read.)

Anyways, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're lucky you're using an image. That means you already know the height of the div. You get to use other fixed-height solutions like line-height applied to the <ul>. On the other hand, I'm dealing with fluid height, and am still looking for an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Vertical-align:middle` aligns the median of child element to the median of parent element. If all child elements have `float:left`, then the parent has a height of 0px and hence its median is above the child elements.

So, you might add a `<br style='clear:both' />` after your menu and the DIV will finally get its vertical size.

Comment: I added the `<br style='clear:both' />`, set a height attribute on `#head`, and put `vertical-align: middle` on the `#logo` and `#nav` IDs, but they still align to the top.

Comment: But actually, why do you need `float:left` for the UL element?

Comment: anyway, floated elements are 'taken out' of the regular text stream, so "vertical-align" attribute does not apply to them. A simple workaround to align the figures is to set `padding-top` of the image.

Comment: if it's variable height, padding-top can't be used. Any other solutions?

Comment: I hate so much Web because of tricks like `<br style='clear:both' />`

Answer (score 0):

table with single row comes handy here.

```
<div id="head">

<table>
<tr>

<td>
  <h1>Fluid Heading</h1>
</td>

<td style="width: 5%">
  <img id="logo" src="logo.png" />
</td>

<td style="width: 5%">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</td>

</tr>
</table>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.head td { vertical-align: middle; }
```