# Vertical-align with text in a div doesnt work

Tags: html, css

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4okrg7L7/).

From the explanation [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_vertical-align), and here [How to use vertical-align: middle; properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439267/how-to-use-vertical-align-middle-properly) and... a lot of other ones, but I just want to vertical align my text in all divs that are immediate children of the class `irow`..

If I add an image with style `vertical-align: middle;`, the text following seems to be aligned. If I remove the image, text is not aligned anymore. I've tried to follow the suggestion [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_vertical-align&preval=baseline) which puts the text in a `span` and apply `vertical-align` to the span without success. I tried with the hack `position:relative;top:50%` without success too. So here's the solution that aligns the text, but, of course, I want to make it work on all divs, and without the image!

```
<style>
.irow > div {
    height: 80px;
    min-height: 60px;
}
.irow div:nth-child(4n+1), .irow div:nth-child(4n+2) {
  background-color: #2b669a;
}
.irow div:nth-child(4n+3), .irow div:nth-child(4n+4) {
  background-color: #46b8da;
}
</style>
<div class="irow">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <img style="height:80px; vertical-align: middle; outline: solid 1px #34fffe" src="http://www.animaux.arroukatchee.fr/babouin/babouin.jpg">
        Inès va morfler grave
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <a class="btn btn-default btn" href="#" role="button">Go »</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <img style="height:80px; vertical-align: middle; outline: solid 1px #34fffe" src="http://www.animaux.arroukatchee.fr/babouin/babouin.jpg">
        Inès que des mots&nbsp;!
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <a class="btn btn-default btn" href="#" role="button">Go »</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Basic duplicate? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two ways:
1) simulate the presence of `img` using `:before` :

```css
.irow > div {
    height: 80px;
    min-height: 60px;
}
.irow > div:before{
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:0;
  height:80px;
}
.irow div:nth-child(4n+1), .irow div:nth-child(4n+2) {
  background-color: #2b669a;
}
.irow div:nth-child(4n+3), .irow div:nth-child(4n+4) {
  background-color: #46b8da;
}
```

```html
<div class="irow">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <img style="height:80px; vertical-align: middle; outline: solid 1px #34fffe" src="http://www.animaux.arroukatchee.fr/babouin/babouin.jpg">
        Inès va morfler grave
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <a class="btn btn-default btn" href="#" role="button">Go »</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <img style="height:80px; vertical-align: middle; outline: solid 1px #34fffe" src="http://www.animaux.arroukatchee.fr/babouin/babouin.jpg">
        Inès que des mots&nbsp;!
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <a class="btn btn-default btn" href="#" role="button">Go »</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

or 2) simply use `line-height` for one-lined text(wont work for multilined text):

```css
.irow > div {
    height: 80px;
    min-height: 60px;
    line-height:80px;
}
.irow div:nth-child(4n+1), .irow div:nth-child(4n+2) {
  background-color: #2b669a;
}
.irow div:nth-child(4n+3), .irow div:nth-child(4n+4) {
  background-color: #46b8da;
}
```

```html
<div class="irow">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <img style="height:80px; vertical-align: middle; outline: solid 1px #34fffe" src="http://www.animaux.arroukatchee.fr/babouin/babouin.jpg">
        Inès va morfler grave
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <a class="btn btn-default btn" href="#" role="button">Go »</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <img style="height:80px; vertical-align: middle; outline: solid 1px #34fffe" src="http://www.animaux.arroukatchee.fr/babouin/babouin.jpg">
        Inès que des mots&nbsp;!
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <a class="btn btn-default btn" href="#" role="button">Go »</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

to be honest, there are much more ways, such as using `display:table-cell` or display flex, but i dont like them

Comment: Thank you very much indeed! But why you dont like "display: flex;" with "align-items:center"?